# Eigenvalues of the matrix $AA^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Suppose $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ and let $B=A A^*$.

Show that all the eigenvalues of $B$ are non-negative real.

Can you please give me an hint how to start the proof?

All I know is that $B$ is a product of the matrix $A$ with its conjugate and I can't see how it helps me.

Comment: Do you know anything about how hermitian matrices relate to diagonalizability?

Comment: @GitGud Yes - every hermitian matrix is normal and therefore diagonalizable.

Comment: More can be said, in fact any hermitian matrix is unitarily similar to a real diagonal matrix. Anyway, do you know how definiteness (i.e. being positive definite, semipositive definite, etc) relates to the signs of the eigenvalues?

Comment: @GitGud Hmm... I know the first part is correct. "any hermitian matrix is similar to a real diagonal matrix". I didn't understand the last part.

Comment: I edited both parts of my comment.

Comment: Ian's solution is simpler than what I had in mind though.

Comment: @GitGud I don't have an answer to the second part "how definiteness relates to the signs of eigenvalues". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Useful facts: a matrix is positive definite if, and only if, all eigenvalues are positive; a matrix is semipositive definite if, and only if, all eigenvalues are non-negative; etc.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: A followup to Git Gud's points: usually one only says that a matrix is positive definite *with respect to some inner product*. This means that it is self-adjoint with respect to that inner product and has the eigenvalue properties that were mentioned. Out of context the inner product is usually the Euclidean one. But it turns out that one can always choose an inner product to make a matrix with positive eigenvalues be positive definite (and similar for semidefinite and so forth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the adjoint says that:

$$\langle x,Ay \rangle = \langle A^*x,y \rangle$$

if $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$ with respect to $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ and $x,y$ are vectors. We can apply this here to get:

$$\langle x,A A^* x \rangle = \langle A^* x,A^* x \rangle = \| A^* x \|^2.$$

Now consider what happens if $A A^* x = \lambda x$.

Comment: Thank you @Ian  I'm trying to understand your explanation.

Comment: But how the scalar product is related to the eigenvalues signs ?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB Well, $\| A^* x \|^2 \geq 0$. If $A A^* x = \lambda x$ then $\langle x,A A^* x \rangle = \langle x,\lambda x \rangle$. So $\langle x,\lambda x \rangle \geq 0$. Why does this force $\lambda \geq 0$?

Comment: because $\langle x, \lambda x\rangle = \lambda^- \langle x, x\rangle = \lambda^- \|x\|^2 ? $

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB Right.